# how to show seleted fromdate and todate in textbox

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

i have a two textbox which is used to select   from date and two date  to fetch the record from database, i m using spring controller ,service,and DAO to load the data . i am not using ajax for that then how to show that twodate in textbox after refreshing the page also.

I want to show the seledted date in texbox.

Comment: What about HTML5 `<input type="date">`? I must admit I do not completely understand your question though.

Answer (score 0):

You would save the chosen dates somewhere, perhaps in a session type system and then echo them back into the `value` attributes of the `input` elements.